# CakePHP 2.2 - two different app's and one session

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have **one database - (users, administrators).**
I have 2 app. **(application/login, backend/login)**.

So, when I log in at "backend" with my administrator data, I don't want to be logged in with that SAME data on "application".

How can I get **two different sessions for two different applications** in CakePHP under the same browser?

I want to be logged in with **administrators under /backend** and with **user under /application**.

CakePHP 2.2.0.

Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it. In app/Config/core.php:

Application:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'ini' => array(
            'session.cookie_path' => '/application',
        ),
        'cookie' => 'my_cookie',
    ));
```

Backend:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'cake',
        'ini' => array(
            'session.cookie_path' => '/backend',
        ),
        'cookie' => 'my_cookie_2',
    ));
```

Thanks anyway. :D I've learned a lot in this few hours. :D